# How to pass nested class to type in @ApiOkResponse or create appropriate custom decorator?

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, typescript-decorator, nestjs-swagger

### Background:

I used nestjs interceptor to put returned data from controller inside `data` property and add some other properties. Now I'd like to use `@ApiOkResponse` that would reflect the nested properties.

#### Controller returns

```js
{
   prop1: 'val1',
   prop2:  'val2'
}
```

#### After it was intercepted it returns

```js
data: {
   prop1: 'val1',
   prop2:  'val2'
},
addedProp: 'addedVal'
```

I also have say two classes:

```js
// Have many variations of similar classes (for different controllers (types of data)
class NotYetIntercepted {
   @ApiProperty()
   prop1: string;

   @ApiProperty()
   prop2: string;
}

class Intercepted<T = any> {
   @ApiProperty()
   data: T;

   @ApiProperty()
   addedProp: string;
}
```

### Challenge

Now I'd like to add to my controllers `@ApiOkResponse({ type: Intercepted })` but also somehow specify that `data` property of class `Intercepted` should be of type `NotYetIntercepted`.

I tried creating a custom decorator like this:

```js
import { ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { ApiProperty, ApiResponseOptions, ApiOkResponse } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Intercepted } from '@appnamespace/models';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export const CustomApiOkResponse = (notYetIntercepted: Function, options?: Omit<ApiResponseOptions, 'type'>) => {

  class InterceptedWithData extends Intercepted {

    @ApiProperty()
    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(() => notYetIntercepted)
    data: typeof notYetIntercepted;
  }

  return ApiOkResponse({
    ...options,
    type: InterceptedWithData,
  });
};
```

That didn't work. When I removed `@Type() => notYetIntercepted)` and set `data` as `data: notYetIntercepted` it sort of worked somehow (with typescript warning) but it overridden all values in my swagger docs to whatever was the last passed value to (`@CustomApiOkResponse(AnotherNotYetIntercepted)`).

I know I could create a class for each nested data type but is there a cleaner solution?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pass the Swagger schema dynamically using your custom Decorator. In nestjs/terminus something very similar has been done - see [`health-check.decorator.ts`](https://github.com/nestjs/terminus/blob/c071d692de2a1084ee5d5b51c92f3be253f4dc83/lib/health-check/health-check.decorator.ts#L16-L19) and [`health-check.schema.ts`](https://github.com/nestjs/terminus/blob/c071d692de2a1084ee5d5b51c92f3be253f4dc83/lib/health-check/health-check.schema.ts#L31-L52).

In a nutshell, you can pass the custom definitions via the `schema` option.

```js
export const CustomApiOkResponse = (notYetIntercepted: Function, options?: Omit<ApiResponseOptions, 'type'>) => {
  return ApiOkResponse({
    ...options,
    schema: {
     // .. your Swagger Schema
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with circular dependencies when tried to set type on `@ApiOkResponse`, and my problem have been solved by removing all `null` values properties in `DTO`. Nest refusing null as type in `DTO`.